# htaccess redirect with P tag

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, proxy

I'm not familiar with the apache config. I want to redirect a domain name to another one without changing the URL in the address bar, I heard that we can redirect with P flag. but It always give me 500 internal server.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.website\.net$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain2.website.net/pagenumber1  [P]
```

Meanwhile, [R=301,L] works fine for me but it will adapt the new domain name which I don't want to.

I have mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http ON already. Please give advice what could be wrong?

Update: They are on the same server with different directories.

Comment: what does your error log say?

Comment: @starkeen Hi, do you know where I can find the error log, I'm not very familiar working on the server, I only got the ftp to edit the htaccess file only. Somebody else will help me config the apache but they also don't know about this.